# In wordpress start an animation on after the page has been fully loaded

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, animation

I have a wordpress site, and I added some "raw html" element with some animation to it.
The problem is, the animations start with the page load, and don't wait for the preloader to finish, and the page itself shown.

Does the preloader stop once the page is loaded? (I believe the page keeps doing more staff after being "loaded")

I am a newbie to wordpress (and indid to JS) so, I am not editing the wordpress php/js files themeselves... only using a "RAW HTML" element.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable coding such things, I suggest you to take a look at plugins like AniJS combined with ScrollReveal.

You can then put this on any tag (body, p, div, ...)

```
data-anijs="if: DOMContentLoaded, on: window, do: yourAnimation animated, before: scrollReveal, after: holdAnimClass"
```

DOMContentLoaded (and other loading options) checks if the navigator has loaded the whole page, for then playing the animation on scroll (you can do without scroll too by removing "before: scrollReveal" and then holds the class of the animation so that it don't loop forever.

Comment: Is it WordPress compatible?

Comment: "add some raw css/html animation", as i understood this, your purpose was to change your html files with the animations. So what you basically have to do is uploading this file (anijs-helper-scrollreveal-min.js) to your wp, if you don't know how take a look here : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-upload-js-files
include then this plugins to your wp_footer / footer with the correct path 
(<script src="PATH/scrollReveal.js"></script>)

Comment: Mmmm I see your confusion. I forgot to write that I am using "raw HTML element" as a column item. That is, god forbidden, not editing any real script in the site, as I am a newbie... But I will update my question now.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is still hard to understand, can you, or not edit the HTML of your wordpress page? It seemed like so, so I offered you a way of animating on load etc, only in html, you just have to include a line in your wordpress files, that isn't hard. :-)

Comment: I wish to avoid touching core WordPress files as much as I can. My guess, there is a solution within WordPress...

Answer (score 0):

Put you animation JS in this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

function is executed when the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: One thing I do not understand, can *document.ready( function() )* be called more than once? Because if not, it wouldn't be wise to call it, persumably again after the wordpress js code had called it...